# close jquery autocomplete if query is not like data

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsonp, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a script which allows to display Google suggestions. The problem is that it STILL displays the list even when the value of input is different than the data available, I rather have it closed. Take a look at this Fiddle: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xbpk7/1/)

Type a letter than some rubbish like 'cjfsdkcrdvhcxrbsks' You will see the list is still showing. So how do I close it if the value does not match the suggestions?

Comment: I changed the fiddle an updated the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually got an error if you have a look in the console.

When the search does not return results, **the object `data.query.results.toplevel` is null**. As you don't check for that, there is an exception when trying to access `data.query.results.toplevel.CompleteSuggestion` and the menu does not close simply because the code just stops working.

Check for null for `data.query.results.toplevel` and in case it is null, use `response([]);` to close the menu:

```
success: function(data) {

    if (typeof data == 'string') {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
    }

    if (data.query.results.toplevel === null) {
        // passing an empty array to response callback closes the menu
        response([]);
        return;
    }

    response(
        $.map(
        data.query.results.toplevel.CompleteSuggestion,
            function(item) {
                return {
                    label: item.suggestion.data,
                    value: item.suggestion.data
                };
        }));
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/QjvL2/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
 success: function(data) {

          if (typeof data == 'string') data = $.parseJSON(data);
          if (data.query.results.toplevel == null){
                   $(this).autocomplete("close"); return;
          }
```

just checked what the page returns using firebug and this should work, hopefully